# How to set laravel on GCP with https instead of http?

Tags: laravel, ssl, https

I'm hosting my Laravel project on GCP(google cloud platform).
When using facebook-login-api, it says my website callback url has to be 
 in https.

Comment: Does your site have an ssl certificate?

Comment: Not yet. Where can I get an ssl certificate?

Comment: This might point you in the right direction: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-managed-ssl-for-google-app-engine Otherwise, I would look into LetsEncrypt.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like what I am searching for. I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a post of what I wanted with CentOS 7.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-7

Follow this post above can create self-signed SSL Certificate for https used, about it's not verified so it will show that your website is dangerous before getting in.

After testing my function works well I bought a real SSL Certificate on
https://cheapsslsecurity.com/

Hope this can help somebody.

Comment: Why would you buy a certificate when you can get one for free?

Comment: Because it's not verified certificate so it still shows that my website is dangerous when someone enters in for the first time.    
For some users, they won't get in the website with that dangerous warning.

Comment: All certificates have some degree of validation. I assume you are arguing for OV over DV which does not actually offer any real advantage, especially if you don't actually have an official organization behind you, Perhaps if you have insights which are not covered at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18919/are-there-technical-disadvantages-in-using-free-ssl-certificates you should post an answer there explaining in more detail what you mean. Or perhaps you are simply unaware of https://letsencrypt.org/ and similar free services?

Comment: @tripleee Your comments really help me a lot, I never go deep with the different of the paid and free SSL certificate. And I'm unaware of letsencrypt.org before.  I will use the certificate from letsencrypt.org next time on my project.
Thank you!!